# How Can I Get a Jquery Mobile Button to Open Specific Collapsible List Id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, jquery-mobile

I am trying to code a Jquery mobile application (latest release) so when the JQM button is clicked, a SPECIFIC collapsible list id is opened and positioned into view. This button should allow for toggle. The list id to be opened is id=set2. Please help I have checked everywhere with no luck.

Here is my current code...

JQM Button Code...

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="expand">Find It</a>
```

### HTML

```
<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d" id="set">
    <div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Header 1</h3>
        <p>SOME CODE HERE</p>
    </div>

    <div data-role="collapsible" id="set2" data-collapsed="true">
        <h3>Header 2</h3>
        <p>SOME CODE HERE</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("pageinit", function() {
       $("a#expand").click(function() {
           $("#set2").trigger( "expand" );
       });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

i created a fiddle for you that works:
http://jsfiddle.net/acturbo/FZbyh/

here is the jquery code:

```
//$(document).on("pageinit", function() {
$().ready(function() {

    // the "a" should not be needed
    //$("a#expand").on("click", function() {
    $("#expand").on("click", function() {
        $("#set2").trigger( "expand" );
    });

});
```

html:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" data-theme="a" id="expand">Find It</a>

<div data-role="collapsible-set" data-content-theme="d" id="set">

<div data-role="collapsible" id="set1" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>Header 1</h3>
    <p>SOME CODE HERE</p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" id="set2" data-collapsed="true">
    <h3>Header 2</h3>
    <p>SOME CODE HERE</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Anythony, your solutions works on jsfiddle, but not on my live site. I have tried everything and can seem to find the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue. It was caused by the placement of the script code and id name "exapand", since this is a option for the trigger event the id must consist of a different name.